# Red words in bibliography structure tree in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio

I am using LaTeX for a few months now and already have completed my first report with it.

Recently I switched to TeXstudio and made an outline for my thesis. However, in the the bibliography part of the structure tree it shows parts of the thesis in red. 
I have tried to find out what causes this but could not find a solution, so I ended up here.

Anyone knows what causes this? I tried to attach an screenshot of it but I do not have enough reputation.

*Apparently, TeXstudio was a little buggy. The red markings appeared when I opened all the .tex files at once. When I open the master .tex file the red marking disappeared. Check out the screenshots.

Furthermore, thanks for the additional info. I will read the stuff on how to add a MWE and will use it in future posts.

[image: red words] 
[image: no red words]

Comment: The `hyperref` package would do this - do you have it in your preamble?  It would help if you could post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we could know for sure what you're talking about.  (Oh! And [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436))  On the other hand, I might be misinterpreting your question entirely - If it ain't text, post a screenshot.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: With the edit, I'm not really sure whether there is actually a question here at all!